# uPnp SetAVTransportURI Missing SOAP action header

Tags: soap, xmlhttprequest, action, upnp, dlna

I am playing about with bubbleUpnp and looking at uPnp in general. I've put out a urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaRenderer:1 discovery and the app notifies of its capabilities.

The first issue is I have xmbc on different devices, ps3, ps4 all can see each other but only the bubbleUpnp and my router replies ( that goes for ssdp:all to).

trying to get set a AVTransportURI on bubbleUpnp i keep getting a uPnp error

```
<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>UPnPError</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <UPnPError xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:control-1-0">
                    <errorCode>401</errorCode>
                    <errorDescription>No action by that name at this service. Missing SOAP action header.</errorDescription>
                </UPnPError>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But grabbing the header from charles shows its there.

```
POST
/dev/9bfe134f-b027-52f3-ffff-ffffaae644dd/svc/upnp-org/AVTransport/
action HTTP/1.1 Host    192.168.1.65:58645 Accept   */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate Content-Length    429
Content-Type    text/xml; charset=utf-8 Accept-Language en-us
soapaction  urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#
SetAVTransportURI Connection    keep-alive
User-Agent  channelListingTest/1 CFNetwork/758.3.15 Darwin/15.4.0
```

heres the soap request

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:SetAVTransportURI xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">
            <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
            <CurrentURI>http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4</CurrentURI>
            <CurrentURIMetaData />
        </u:SetAVTransportURI>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and under the soap tab in charles it looks ok to me

```
SetAVTransportURI   Method  
Parameters  Element 
[InstanceID: null]  Element 0
[CurrentURI: null]  Element http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4
[CurrentURIMetaData: null]  Element
```

It could be my in experience with soap/upnp does anything stick out ?

Cheers

edit heres the code to send the request.

```
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("POST", "http://192.168.1.65:58645/dev/9bfe134f-b027-52f3-ffff-ffffaae644dd/svc/upnp-org/AVTransport/action");

                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        console.log(request.responseText)
                };

                let setAVTransport = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                                        '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
                                                '<u:SetAVTransportURI xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">' +
                                                    '<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>' +
                                                      '<CurrentURI>http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4</CurrentURI>' +
                                                    '<CurrentURIMetaData></CurrentURIMetaData>' +
                                                '</u:SetAVTransportURI>' +
                                            '</s:Body>' +
                                        '</s:Envelope>';

            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            request.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#SetAVTransportURI");

                request.send(setAVTransport);
```

Comment: Please paste headers exactly as seen on the wire, it's currently impossible to tell if they are correct or not (e.g. is the soap action value quoted or not, or is it correctly in one line)

Comment: Hi thanks, heres the code - i think it might be my network settings on the dev machine as kodi doesnt see anything from it ( except again for bubbleupnp).

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise this is the real issue but the SOAPAction value should be in doublequotes (don't ask me, I don't think it makes any sense either).

Try something like this:

```
request.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#SetAVTransportURI\"");
```

In general I advice to check the actual messages on the network (wireshark is a great tool) and compare them to messages sent by a client that does work.

Comment: Thanks, i feel daft the code was actually fine - on the search request I wasn't adding a "\r\n" on the last param. Once this was done I could see every upnp. The code posted works with kodi and others now (the search before would only should bubblepnp) but bubblepnp still moans lol. Its a start ! , thanks for the time :-) .
And yeah , wireshark help me find that error :-) 
thanks again !

Comment: That's good to hear. I don't want to be a killjoy but the fact that the code works with one implementation doesn't mean it is fine. If you sent the soap message to the correct  host and it responded with the 401, there's obviously still a problem.